# How do I backup SharePoint hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, backup

I have deployed heavily used SharePoint 2013 app to one of my customer . The app frequently need changes. Since I'm using incremental development, I need a solid back up strategy at each app upgrade

My question is How do I back up a SharePoint hosted app? .  According to the TechNet it is not a straightforward.

Back up an app :https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj871017.aspx

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just house the iterative versions within Visual Studio Online or some other version control?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to backup client data inside of your SharePoint App or for backing up the App source code itself? The article you reference would be about the client's data in your App, for this specific case.

Comment: Hi john / Elvis ,
I need a proper rollback plan in case of an app upgrade failure . Up to now I haven't had serious issues at app upgrade but I need to ready for the worst before it happens .I also need to test the restoring process in testing environment before carried out any action in production.

Comment: Elvis , I'm using VSS 2013 to control my App source. My question is related to role back plan at the production  deployment in case of failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not straight forward, and can be troublesome trying to restore them. If you restore over the top of your existing deployment - things usually work. Your support databases will/should still be in sync with your content (assuming recent backup being restored).

If you try to restore to a different site or farm, things tend to not go as well (it's not as easy as just restoring the backup, you have to consider the config and subscription, and app databases).  This is usually a bad idea.

Usually the only thing I need to keep is the contents.  I backup (with PowerShell) the content that I need, which is usually list or library data.  If I need to redeploy the App to a new site or farm, I just deploy a new app and then redeploy the content.

I recently had to do this with an App that actually wouldn't upgrade after some changes were made to the URL paths for workflow manager.  The app would fail during upgrade, it also failed to roll back and was stuck in read only mode.  We had to restore from database backup, then backup contents of app, remove the app, deploy new version and then deploy the content.

Based on your particular needs here - I would plan on backing up the database.  I've had OK results with site collection backups, mixed results with app web backups, but "reverting" to a previous version works best by just backing up and restoring the entire content database.  I have not had an issue with method yet.

**Edit**

1). *In your case you have backed up only the Content Database. what about Configuration, Secure Store Service application, App Management service application databases?*

You back those up for full recovery.  If you start restoring those for every app update or rollback your farm will end up in a world of hurt.  You need these things for specific parts of your deployment.  If you restore from a backup taken 24 hours of just the content DB everything will work fine

2). *Did you have any problem with the in-progress workflows after restoring the app?*

After restoring the app, usually the in-progress workflows have to be killed and restarted.  I personally would rather deal with that, than restoring the workflow and service bus databases anyway.  I especially would not restore service databases that will affect more than just the app in question.

Overall – a good recovery strategy is always a must.  However, you should not have to lean on it for deploying an app.  If you are unsure of changes and don’t have a development / test server, deploy another site collection and push out there first.  It’s isolated from your other content so it’s just as good as a standalone testing environment.   If you host this up, no biggie, but better done here than inside a production app that is in use.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Jesus
I have some questions to you .
1).In your case you have backed up only the Content Database . what about Configuration ,Secure Store Service application , App Management service application databases ?
2).Did you have any problem with the in-progress workflows after restoring the app? 

Can you share your back up script steps, so I can understand everything what you have done.
Cheers!!

Comment: I have dev and testing environment .But I wanted to prepare for the worst. I have a plan to set up worst case scenario . 

1).Deploying and app 
2).Play around it
3).Do a code level change to both workflow and app 
4).Do a upgrade and make it fail 
5).Do a restore and check how things went 

I'll share my findings once I do this test.